Polylang Removes Slash from French Product URLs (e.g., /frproduct-name/ instead of /fr/product-name/)
I’m using Polylang on my WordPress site, but only French product URLs are losing their slashes on load. For example, https://www.lasercutter-vergleichen.de/fr/product-name/ changes to https://www.lasercutter-vergleichen.de/frproduct-name/.
It can be tested by entering the wwwlasercutter-vergleichen.de/fr/shop page.
Tried Solutions:
Cleared cache (using LiteSpeed Cache) and deactivated it temporarily.
Added .htaccess rules to enforce slashes.
Re-saved permalinks multiple times.
Anyone encountered this or have solutions? Thanks!

Here's the curl result, which indicates Rank Math makes the redirect. Please go to Rank Math SEO → General Settings → Redirections and check if any settings could cause such an issue.
curl -I https://www.lasercutter-vergleichen.de/fr/shop/test/
HTTP/2 301
x-dns-prefetch-control: on
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
x-redirect-by: Rank Math
x-litespeed-cache-control: public,max-age=604800
x-litespeed-tag: 3b4_HTTP.200,3b4_HTTP.301,3b4_product,3b4_URL.960962af0b9458a73212b958130b3288,3b4_Po.4085,3b4_guest,3b4_
set-cookie: PHPSESSID=7e9c5abd7c39d874fd7f1f16bec5fed8; path=/
location: https://www.lasercutter-vergleichen.de/frtest/
vary: User-Agent
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 13 Nov 2024 07:52:59 GMT
server: Apache



Ok I guess that helps a lot find the settings which causes the issue :D.
But I want to keep The settings figured out that RankMath wrote a statement for that :D
https://rankmath.com/kb/polylang-compatibility/
Thanks a lot!

No problem, happy to help.
